# Send image data via HTTP POST

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator

How do I send image data via HTTP POST?

I have the following code:

```
NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://demo25.projectproofonline.com/soul_mate_modified/save.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl
cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy  timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

So one way to do this would be by doing a multipart image upload however this would not be in json format however this is indeed normal practice and may be your only option.
[Multipart/Formdata image upload, get the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561403/multipart-formdata-image-upload-get-the-file)